# flexible table in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a form php page that sends information about jobs. Each `user` can register unlimited jobs, so I need a flexible table in my database that when `user` insert new `job`, the table will get the values and save the information as `job 1`,`job 2` ... `job n`.

Is there a way or maybe a simpler way?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Add more info, like tables used, sample data, expected result...

Comment: @jarlh: what info u need? i just want a flexible table in sql. is that unclear or hard? people just like to dislike a post it is when they do not know anything of coding. i just asked a simple question bah!!

Comment: This sounds like you are heading towards some really bad database design. Constantly bumping out the number of columns to max(count(jobs)) is going to do nothing but cause you heartache down the line. Instead you should have a table that has `user | job` where a `user` has many records.

Comment: @sajad, to answer you question, Yes, "Flexible table" is unclear. That's not an actual term that I, personally, have ever heard. It could probably use some definition in your question like "A table whose columns grow dynamically to account for the maximum number of jobs submitted for any single user" or something along those lines. I might be wrong and maybe "Flexible Table" is a thing in some RDBMS, but my gut tells me it's probably not a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand on my comment:

Your best bet here is a table for users:

```
user_id | name | other | attributes | for | a | user | like | birthdate
```

And a seperate table for the user's relationship to a job

```
user_id | job_id
```

If you need to store information about a job, then do it in yet another table

```
job_id | job_name | other | attributes | for | a | job
```

Now your database schema doesn't have to change dynamically as new data comes in. The only thing that grows is your record count. This is proper database design. You can query for all the job names associated to a user:

```
SELECT user.name, job.job_name
FROM user
    INNER JOIN user_job ON user.user_id = user_job.user_id
    INNER JOIN job ON user_job.job_id = job.job_id
WHERE user.user_id = 123
```

The direction you were heading where your schema changes as new data comes in will cause you nightmare scenarios down the line and should be avoided at all costs. For instance, imagine the same query where the number of job columns grows as new data comes in:

```
SELECT user.name, user.job1, user.job2, user.job3... how do I know where to stop for this user?
FROM user
WHERE user_id = 123
```

Comment: thanks friend, ur answer is simple and will help me too much, so i need three table, can u please tell me what is | for | a | user | like | ? thanks friend u r a great man...

Comment: ok i got , u mean was any attribute that i can add, correct?

Comment: Yep, just whatever attribute. A table's record should be a 1:1 type deal. So if your table is `user` it should only contain attributes of a `user`. Since user:job is 1:many, then `job` gets it's own table with it's own attributes. Glad it was helpful!

Comment: which ones are primary keys?

Comment: I would probably use userid for the user table, both userid and jobid for the relationship table, and jobid for the job table.

Comment: can you take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550554/insert-to-all-cells-when-records-are-more-than-one-php